# Is it hard to figure out why some questions are highlighted?

Tags: feature-request

Or am I an idiot? The highlighted questions were the only thing I had trouble immediately figuring out on the SF GUI. For ages I thought they were questions I had viewed, then no, maybe answered? No... Finally I took the time to work it out.

Maybe also highlight the tags that are causing the question to be highlighted, with a different colored border for example?

Comment: Are you asking us to comment or vote on the two options you've presented?

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

[image: Highlighted Question]

Come from this:

[image: Favorite Tags]

Comment: If you're saying put giant crudely-drawn red circles on the page, then yes that would work, but probably won't get approved. If you're saying that I should have been able to figure it out because of the favorite tags list at the right, I saw that, and it was not intuitive for me.

Comment: What would have made it intuitive is if the tags in the list of Favorite Tags had a slightly different style, and that same style was used for the favorite tag(s) in the question.

Comment: I should also add that the source of the highlighted questions for me is `Frequented Tags`. As opposed to Favorite Tags, they are not created by any specific action I performed.

Comment: If you define Favorite tags then Frequented Tags is replaced. But yea, that's it.